# Zoo Visitor and Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, extension, zoo-visitor

I'm building a member/ecommerce site with CartThrob and Zoo Visitor.

I have a multi-page checkout.
From looking around for solutions on how to do this, people have said to use the Zoo Visitor update profile tags on the shipping/billing pages, and use hidden ZV fields inside the Cartthrob checkout tag on the payment page.

This works fine except for a few cases:

- If you want guests to checkout, this approach won't work.
- Calculating tax and/or shipping won't work until submitting the final checkout form.

I've solved the first issue by conditionally showing a CT save_member_info form if they are logged out and a ZV profile form if they are logged in.

I can probably save the address to session by posting to CT's save_member_info using AJAX when submitting a ZV form, but that feels clunky.

Cartthrob usually calculates tax/shipping by the member data in the session. It doesn't get saved to session when using ZV forms.

Is it possible to map the ZV fields to the CT session data when saving the ZV profile form? I'm sure you need to use an extension but that's beyond me. Does anything like this already exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin Kimbrell of Objective HTML helped with an extension that would sync the ZV member data to the session whenever the profile was updated.

Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with a similar situation here where I'm forced to use ZV and finding it difficult to integrate with CT. Is that ZV sync extension available somewhere?